# Using a point in a name with jquery validation

Tags: jquery, validation

The names of the fields I need to validate contain a point. Using the validation extension of Jquery I do this:

```
$('#IDENTITY_DETAILS').validate({
    ignore: "input[type='text']:hidden",
    rules: {
        HOLDERS_PERSONAL.BIRTHDAY: { required: true, validateBirthday: true },
        ...
    },
    messages: {
        HOLDERS_PERSONAL.BIRTHDAY:{
            required: "Please fill in your birthday.",
            validateBirthday: "Please fill in a valid birthday."
        },
        ...
    },
```

But this of course gives an error.
how can I use a point this way? I HAVE to use a point. Don't tell me not to use it. If you know a way how to set the rules and messages using id's, that's fine to.

I know it's possible to set the rules seperatly and thus using the id, but I also need to set the messages with names and I don't think there is a seperate way to set the messages like the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem some time ago. It wasn't possible to use a point in HOLDERS_PERSONAL.BIRTHDAY. It seems that in the end the CRM that I used, could also work with BIRTHDAY as name.

In summary, a point in the name is not a good idea and should never be done.

Answer (score -1):

```
rules: {
        "HOLDERS_PERSONAL.BIRTHDAY": { required: true, validateBirthday: true },
        ...
    },
    messages: {
            "HOLDERS_PERSONAL.BIRTHDAY":{
                required: "Please fill in your birthday.",
                validateBirthday: "Please fill in a valid birthday."
            },
```

Try this

Comment: It makes the Jquery work but now my custom error messages don't dissapear when you fill in the field correctly, so I don't think this works :/

Comment: Hm. Is validation on blur enabled?

Comment: I do this for blur:$('input[type="text"]').blur(function() { $("#IDENTITY_DETAILS").validate().element(this); });

Comment: Sec. I'm talking not about that

Comment: [Options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) - those onsubmit, onfocusout, onkeyup - are those options set to true in your code?

Comment: with those options you do not need to do this `$('input[type="text"]').blur(function() { $("#IDENTITY_DETAILS").validate().element(this); });`